# Count searched words - rstudio

Tags: rstudio

How can I (if possible) get a count of total number of occurrences, in my Rscript, of a search, when searching for it using the "Find/Replace" feature in rstudio?

For example, say I had the following script:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
print(a)
print("Are you there?")
```

Then when going Ctrl + F (or commands + F on mac), and typing a (lowercase), somewhere it would say 2.

I am running version 3.5.1 on MAC.

The following image should help clarify the feature I am talking about,

[image]

Comment: So to clarify, you want an R script to search inside its own code for a specific string?

Comment: I'll add an image for clarity, I am just talking about the rstudio interface, I will remove the r tag to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to Find and Replace with an identical string. If you find `a` and replace all with `a` it won't change your code, but will say "2 occurrences replaced".

Note that you need to check `Match case`, otherwise `A` will also be matched (and replaced with `a`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to achieve this in RStudio, however you can convert your code to a string and then search the string using the `stringr` package.

Using your example:

```
my.code = '  a <- c(1,2,3)
  print(a)
  print("Are you there?") '

> my.code
[1] "  a <- c(1,2,3)\n  print(a)\n  print(\"Are you there?\") "
```

Now to search for lowercase "a":

```
library(stringr)
str_count(my.code, "a")
[1] 2
```